# Android : ScrollView stretches background image

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I would like to use the scrollview in a login form with a  background image but the image stretches.

my code looks like the following :

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     android:id="@+id/login_layout" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="270dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/login" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/username_login" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username_login"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text" />

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/password_login" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I have 2 text edits for username and password and a login button

the

```
android:background="@drawable/login"
```

is a background image of the layout holding the text edits and button

any help please ?

knowing that i set the background (that stretches) inside the activity

I am setting the background inside the activity

```
private void setBackground(){


        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.login_layout);
        layout.setBackgroundDrawable(application.getBackground01());

    }
```

Comment: android:background="@drawable/login" set this in your ScrollView itself

Comment: Did you try android:src instead of android:background?

Comment: i edited my post please check it

Comment: @AndroSelva is there any android:src for LinearLayout????

Comment: Are you sure that you're not stretching it yourself with android:layout_width="250dp"  android:layout_height="270dp" these two lines?

Comment: @PadmaKumar I didn't go through his code. I just thought he was referring a ImageView..

Comment: put the background drawable as the scrollview background

Answer (score 2):

After so many research got the solution:

Step1: remove the below line from .xml file

```
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

Step2(a): If you are trying in Activity set the onCreate as

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    .... 
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.image_resourcename);
    ....
}
```

Step2(b): If you are trying in Fragment set the onCreateView as

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .... 
    getActivity().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.image_resourcename);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code. Hope is will work.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/login_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="270dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/username_login" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/username_login"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/edit_text"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingTop="2dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/password_login" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: in some forms i have more than i child to the scroll view and it doesn't allow me to do this so i have to have the scroll view as the main parent.

do you have another solution ?

Comment: I am not getting you if you have more than one child then enter those child in first linear layout of scroll view.